# Defining macros based on environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments, conditionals

Right now, I have two macros, `\intersects` and `\union`, that simply point back to `\cap` and `\cup` respectively. Unfortunately, to have nice typesetting in display-like environments, I need to use `\bigcap` and `\bigcup`, right? Is there any way I can define `\union` one way for standard use (no particular environment) and another way for anything else?

Comment: Not really `\cup` is designed for infix use (like `+`) `\bigcup` is already defined to have large/small variants and be used as a prefix operator like `\sum` so they have different usage not directly related to inline/display.

Comment: David is right, but if you *really* want something like that, `\mathpalette` should be useful (AFAIR):

`\def\union{\mathpalette{\bigcup}{\cup}{\cup}{\cup}}`.

Comment: @mbork But nobody would want that.

Comment: I suppose that's fair. So maybe just `\def` something like `\iunion` or `\iintersects` for the iterative variants (`\bigcup`/`\bigcap`)?

Comment: @vermiculus: True to your question about conditional typesetting: You can test for the current environment name (stored in `\@currenvir`). However, this requires you to use `\begin{<env>}`...`\end{<env>}`, otherwise `\[`...`\]` might cause problems. The last example can be alleviated when using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) since it equates the macro to the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no other answer has been proffered I'll extend my comment as an answer:

`\cup` is designed for infix use (like `+`) `\bigcup` is already defined to have large/small variants and be used as a prefix operator like `\sum` so they have different usage not directly related to inline/display.

Examples of usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth.2\textwidth
\parindent0pt
\parskip\baselineskip
\begin{document}

inline cup:\\
$ a \cup b \cup c$

display cup
\[ a \cup b \cup c\]

inline bigcup\\
$\bigcup_{i=0}^3a_i$

display bigcup
\[\bigcup_{i=0}^3a_i\]

\end{document}
```