# Macro for set intersection

Tags: math-mode, macros

I want to create a macro for intersections that can switch between `cap` and `bigcap` depending on the situation. Here is what I came up with based on browsing other posts on the forum. Are there any hazards to this approach? Is there a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\intersect}{\@ifnextchar_{\bigcap}{\cap}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    A \cap B
\]
\[
    A \intersect B
\]
\[
    \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}
\]
\[
    \intersect_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: see my Q: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71150/defining-macros-based-on-environment and check out `mathpalette`

Comment: the hazard comes in when you can't predict exactly what character will come next; if there were no problems with this construction, I've no doubt it would have been done in AMSTeX.  Your use of an operator might not line up with another's use (although presumably,  they would define another descriptive macro).

Comment: @SeanAllred, I looked at that post, but it didn't exactly address my question because I wasn't really concerned about displaystyle versus textstyle: sometimes I want to use `\bigcap` inline and sometimes I want to use `\cap` in displayed math. The real difference for me is whether the intersection is indexed, or just a binary operation.

Comment: In that case, I don't see any problem with this solution ;-)

Comment: technically that is probably as good as anything if you want a switch, but actually I wouldn't do it. It effectively means the infix command is `\intersect` and the prefix command is `\intersect_` both of these are longer than the standard `\cap` and `\bigcap` and unless you define lots of other similar commands makes the command inconsistent with the rest of latex which uses different commands eg `+` and `\sum`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not really concerned about the length of the commands because I use snippets: I am more concerned with having LaTeX source that reads like math than with reducing the length of my commands. But you do make a good point about `+` versus `\sum`: I think maybe I'll just make `\intersect` an alias for `\cap` and `\intersection` an alias for `\bigcap`.

Comment: @David: I think that intersect is a more semantic command compared to cap or bigcap. The length of a macro name should not be a concern at all. I agree with you that one should have a different name for infix and prefix notation.   As for a robust implementation of changing behavior depending on the presence of subscripts and superscripts, see the implementnation of smashiperator in mathtools package (which basically checks both for _ and ^)

Comment: @Aditya on semantic names, yes but `\let\intersect\cap` and `\let\xintersect\bigcap` would address that. On length it shouldn't make a difference but my typing is appalling and probability of typo is correlated to length of word:-)

Comment: @David: your typing would have ben perfect had you switched to vim :)

Comment: @Aditya I should flag that comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you make an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Technically that is probably as good as anything if you want a switch, but actually I wouldn't do it.

It effectively means the infix command is `\intersect` and the prefix command is `\intersect_` both of these are longer than the standard `\cap` and `\bigcap` and unless you define lots of other similar commands makes the command inconsistent with the rest of latex which uses different commands eg `+` and `\sum`.